# How to concatenate near duplicate rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

From the original data, there are duplicated data. The duplicates with different DB have to concat to the back of the former one.Is there any way to merge two tables into one as shown below by comparing between data?

From the original data using drop.duplicates and duplicated, i get two tables and wanted to compare them using dictionaries, but by making rows as dictionaries in both the table, the keys are the same in every dictionary which i can't merge them together.

This is the original data given

```
  DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN
0  M     a     1   NaN
1  M     d     1   NaN
2  M     c     1   NaN
3  N     b     1   NaN
4  N     a     1   NaN
5  N     d     1   NaN
6  O     c     1   NaN
7  O     e     1   NaN
8  O     a     1   NaN
9  O     b     1   NaN
```

By using drop_duplicates and duplicated:

```
  DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN             DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN        
0  M     a     1   NaN           0  N     a     1   NaN        
1  M     d     1   NaN           1  N     d     1   NaN         
2  M     c     1   NaN           2  O     c     1   NaN       
3  N     b     1   NaN           3  O     a     1   NaN
4  O     e     1   NaN           4  O     b     1   NaN
```

This is the kind of dictionary i get from the rows:

```
{'DB': 'N', 'TITLE': 'a', 'ISSN': 1, 'IBSN': 'NaN'}
{'DB': 'M', 'TITLE': 'a', 'ISSN': 1, 'IBSN': 'NaN'}
```

I expect the output to be

```
    DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN   DB TITLE  ISSN ISBN   DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN
0    M     a   1.0   NaN    N     a   1.0  NaN    O     a   1.0   NaN
1    N     b   1.0   NaN    O     b   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    M     d   1.0   NaN    N     d   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    M     c   1.0   NaN    O     c   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    O     e   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

The order of 'TITLE' in the column is not important but the DB have to be sorted alphabetically from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is using `cumcount` to segregate sub-groups, then use `concat` with `join='outer'`:

```
grps = [
    g.set_index('TITLE') for _, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('TITLE').cumcount())
]
pd.concat(grps, join='outer', axis=1, sort=True)

  DB  ISSN  IBSN   DB  ISSN  IBSN   DB  ISSN  IBSN
a  M     1   NaN    N   1.0   NaN    O   1.0   NaN
b  N     1   NaN    O   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
c  M     1   NaN    O   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
d  M     1   NaN    N   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
e  O     1   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

If you need "TITLE" too, use `set_index` with `drop=False`:

```
grps = [
    g.set_index('TITLE', drop=False) 
    for _, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('TITLE').cumcount())
]
pd.concat(grps, join='outer', axis=1, sort=True)

  DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN   DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN   DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN
a  M     a     1   NaN    N     a   1.0   NaN    O     a   1.0   NaN
b  N     b     1   NaN    O     b   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
c  M     c     1   NaN    O     c   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
d  M     d     1   NaN    N     d   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
e  O     e     1   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hi! There's another question here, what if the match requires exact match other than  DB, is that possible to still use cumcount? Which means TITLE ISSN IBSN all must match, else its considered not a duplicate, and must go to another row.

Comment: @WeiLunss Change `df.groupby('TITLE')` to `df.groupby(['TITLE', 'ISSN', 'ISBN'])`, and it should work... if not I suggest opening another question.